# Why does Mattie become angry at Mr. Younger?

Tags: plot-explanation, true-grit

In the ending of True Grit (2010), around 2:10, Mattie says:

> Keep your seat, trash.

Why does Mattie out of a sudden get angry at the seated person?

I may be missing some cultural or historical background here.

Comment: Mr. James doesn't bother taking off his hat or sitting straight, and isn't even showing respect when mr. Younger talks about the death of her friend.

Comment: I loved this movie but I didn't understand either this part. It left me completely confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mattie is not angry at Cole Younger, but at Frank James.

From the [script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/True-Grit.html):

```
  Mattie speaks to two men who sit on the rear platform of the rear car. They are old men
  drinking Coca-Colas. One doffs his hat and rises when Mattie addresses the pair; the other
  stays seated, slurping from his bottle.

                                        Standing Man
                 Yes'm, I am Cole Younger. This is Mr. James. It grieves
                 me to tell you that you have missed Rooster. He passed
                 away, what, three days ago, when the show was in Jonesboro
                 Arkansas. Buried him there in the confederate cemetery.
                 Reuben had a complaint what he referred to as "night hoss"
                                                                                     117
                 and I believe the warm weather was too much for him. We
                 had some lively times. What was the nature of your
                 acquaintance?

                                          Mattie
                 I knew the marshal long ago. We too had lively times.
                 Thank you, Mr. Younger.

  As she turns to go she addresses Frank James, who has been staring at her:

                 . . . Keep your seat, trash.
```

Allen Berra writes in a Daily Beast [article](https://www.thedailybeast.com/give-a-shout-out-to-charles-portis-and-his-extraordinary-novel-true-grit?ref=scroll):

> “Keep your seat, trash,” Mattie snaps as a parting shot to Frank James, who didn’t stand when she approached.

James showed no respect to her, especially considering that she had been informed of Rooster's death, and she is confident enough to snap at him.

An addition from [The Niles Files](http://nilesfilmfiles.blogspot.com/2010/12/particulars-are-in-your-bill-words-and.html):

> Mattie accepts the news, and bids Younger goodbye; she utters to Frank James, "Keep your seat, trash" before leaving, a distinction she possibly makes because of Younger's documented repudiation of his crimes, versus James' blatant exploitation of them.

Cole Younger - from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cole_Younger):

> On August 21, 1912, Cole declared that he had become a Christian and repented of his criminal past.

Frank James - from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frank_James)

> In his final years, James returned to the James Farm, giving tours for the sum of 25 cents.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered good manners to stand for a lady. He remains seated, unbothered. Thus inviting her scorn. Always rise for a lady.